# Big data read subsamples R

Tags: linux, r, awk, system, statistics-bootstrap

I'm most grateful for your time to read this.

I have a uber size 30GB file of 6 million records and 3000 (mostly categorical data) columns in csv format. I want to bootstrap subsamples for multinomial regression, but it's proving difficult even with my 64GB RAM  in my machine and twice that swap file , the process becomes super slow and halts.

I'm thinking about generating subsample indicies in R and feeding them into a system command using sed or awk, but don't know how to do this. If someone knew of a clean way to do this using just R commands, I would be really grateful.

One problem is that I need to pick complete observations of subsamples, that is I need to have all the rows of a particular multinomial observation - they are not the same length from observation to observation. I plan to use glmnet and then some fancy transforms to get an approximation to the multinomial case. One other point is that I don't know how to choose sample size to fit around memory limits.

Appreciate your thoughts greatly.

```
R.version
platform       x86_64-pc-linux-gnu          
arch           x86_64                       
os             linux-gnu                    
system         x86_64, linux-gnu            
status                                      
major          2                            
minor          15.1                         
year           2012                         
month          06                           
day            22                           
svn rev        59600                        
language       R                            
version.string R version 2.15.1 (2012-06-22)
nickname       Roasted Marshmallows
```

Yoda

Comment: You can use the development version of `data.table` (1.8.7) and the function `fread` which will be faster than the most optimized version of `read.table`. data.tables will also be good for data the size you are considering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's an exceedingly terrible idea to use CSV as your data format for such file sizes - why not transform it into a SQLite (or "actual" database) and extract your subsets with SQL queries (using [DBI](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/index.html)/RSQLite[2](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSQLite/index.html))?

You need to import only once, and there is no need to load the entire thing into memory because you can [directly import CSV](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DBI/index.html) files into sqlite.

If in general you want to work with datasets that are larger than your memory, you might also want to have a look at [bigmemory](http://www.bigmemory.org/).

Comment: Thanks, I have the file in a database now. Will make subsample indicies in R and then select the relevant rows using SQL statements to pick each subsample.

Answer (score 1):

As themel has pointed out, R is very very slow on reading csv files.
If you have sqlite, it really is the best approach, as it appears the data mining is not just for
one time, but over multiple session, in multiple ways.

Lets look at the options we have

### Reading the csv to R (slow)

Doing this in R is like 20 times slow, compared to a tool written in C (on my machine)

This is very slow

```
read.csv( file='filename.csv' , head=TRUE , sep=",")
```

### Convert to stata dta file beforehand and load from there

Not that great, but it should work (I have never tried it on a 30 gig file, so I can not say for sure)

### Writing a program to convert csv into dta format(If you know what you are doing)

Using the resource from http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?dta
and code from https://svn.r-project.org/R-packages/trunk/foreign/src/stataread.c to read and write
and http://sourceforge.net/projects/libcsv/
(It has been done in the past. However I have not used it so I do not know how well it performs)

Then using the `foreign` package (http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreign/index.html), a simple

```
library(foreign)
whatever <- read.dta("file.dta")
```

would load your data

### Using mysql directly to import csv data (Hard to use, however it is not that bad if you know SQL)

From s SQL console

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'file.csv' INTO TABLE my_table 
IGNORE 1 LINES              <- If csv file contains headers
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

Or

```
mysql -e "LOAD DATA INFILE 'ls.dat' INTO TABLE mytable1" mydatabase
```

Then play from the R console, using `RMySQL` R interface to the MySQL database
http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/index.html

```
install.packages('RMySQL')
```

Then play around like

```
mydb = dbConnect(MySQL(), user=username, password=userpass, dbname=databasename, host=host)
dbListTables(mydb)
record <- dbSendQuery(mydb, "select * from whatever")
dbClearResult(rs)
dbDisconnect(mydb)
```

### Using R to do all the sqlite/postgreSQL/MySQL backend SQL stuff to import csv (Reccomended)

Download, from https://code.google.com/p/sqldf/ if you do not have the package
or `svn checkout http://sqldf.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ sqldf-read-only`

From the R console,

```
install.packages("sqldf")
# shows built in data frames
data() 

# load sqldf into workspace
library(sqldf)
MyCsvFile <- file("file.csv")
Mydataframe <- sqldf("select * from MyCsvFile", dbname = "MyDatabase", file.format = list(header = TRUE, row.names = FALSE))
```

And off you go!

Presonally, I would recomend the library(sqldf) option :-)

Comment: Tried sqldf, but my file has embedded delimiters, which causes errors. From the documentation, it seems that sqldf can't handle this.

Comment: Yes, that is the reason I wrote about `Using mysql directly to import cvs data`, so you can adjust `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'` to whatever embedded delimiter you are using. There is no known well defined fromat for cvs, so a bit of fiddling around might be required. If you could provide some sample data( few lines ) it would be easier for people in SO to answer :-)

Comment: Having established connections to multiple DBs using RMySQL, how can I query on tables present in different DBs? dbGetQuery seems to allow only one connection in every query.