# R - Why adding 1 column to data table nearly doubles peak memory used?

Tags: r, memory, data.table, large-data

After getting [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28279078/r-how-to-run-average-max-on-different-data-table-columns-based-on-multiple-f) from 2 kind gentlemen, I managed to switch over to data tables from data frame+plyr.

**The Situation and My Questions**

As I worked on, I noticed that *peak memory usage* nearly doubled from 3.5GB to 6.8GB (according to Windows Task Manager) when I added 1 new column using `:=` to my data set containing ~200K rows by 2.5K columns.

I then tried 200M row by 25 col, the increase was from 6GB to 7.6GB before dropping to 7.25GB after a `gc()`.

Specifically regarding adding of new columns, Matt Dowle himself mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358003/tricks-to-manage-the-available-memory-in-an-r-session) that:

> With its := operator you can :
>
> ```
> Add columns by reference
> Modify subsets of existing columns by reference, and by group by reference
> Delete columns by reference
> ```
>
> None of these operations copy the (potentially large) data.table at
>   all, not even once.

Question 1: why would adding a single column of 'NAs' for a DT with 2.5K columns *double* the peak memory used if the data.table is not copied at all?

Question 2: Why does the doubling not occur when the DT is 200M x 25? I didn't include the printscreen for this, but feel free to change my code and try.

**Printscreens for Memory Usage using Test Code**

1. Clean re-boot, RStudio & MS Word opened - 103MB used
   [image: 1. Clean re-boot, RStudio & MS Word opened]
2. Aft running DT creation code but before adding column - 3.5GB used
   [image]
3. After adding 1 Column filled with NA, but before gc() - 6.8GB used
   [image]
4. After running gc() - 3.5GB used
   [image]

**Test Code**

To investigate, I did up the following test code that closely mimics my data set:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)

# Credit: Dirk Eddelbuettel's answer in 
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720983/efficiently-generate-a-random-sample-of-times-and-dates-between-two-dates
RandDate <- function(N, st="2000/01/01", et="2014/12/31") { 
  st <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(st))
  et <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(et))
  dt <- as.numeric(difftime(et,st,unit="sec"))
  ev <- runif(N, 0, dt)
  rt <- as.character( strptime(st + ev, "%Y-%m-%d") )
}

# Create Sample data
TotalNoCol <- 2500
TotalCharCol <- 3
TotalDateCol <- 1
TotalIntCol <- 600
TotalNumCol <- TotalNoCol - TotalCharCol - TotalDateCol - TotalIntCol
nrow <- 200000

ColNames = paste0("C", 1:TotalNoCol)

dt <- as.data.table( setNames( c(

  replicate( TotalCharCol, sample( state.name, nrow, replace = T ), simplify = F ), 
  replicate( TotalDateCol, RandDate( nrow ), simplify = F ), 
  replicate( TotalNumCol, round( runif( nrow, 1, 30 ), 2), simplify = F ), 
  replicate( TotalIntCol, sample( 1:10, nrow, replace = T ), simplify = F ) ), 

    ColNames ) )

gc()

# Add New columns, to be run separately
dt[, New_Col := NA ]  # Additional col; uses excessive memory?
```

**Research Done**

I didn't find too much discussion on memory usage for DT with many columns, only [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988643/big-data-read-subsamples-r) but even then, it's not specifically about memory.

Most discussions on large dataset + memory usage involves DTs with very large rowcount but relatively few columns.

**My System**

Intel i7-4700 with 4-core/8-thread; 16GB DDR3-12800 RAM; Windows 8.1 64-bit; 500GB 7200rpm HDD; 64-bit R; Data Table ver 1.9.4

**Disclaimers**

Please pardon me for using a 'non-R' method (i.e. Task Manager) to measure memory used. Memory measurement/profiling in R is something I still haven't figured out.

---

Edit 1: After updating to data table ver 1.9.5 and re-running. Issue persisted, unfortunately.

[image]

Comment: You can use `?tables` to check the memory usage of your `data.table`'s. I get `3,358MB` before the last column and `3,359MB` after adding that column.

Comment: @shadow, I think you meant `tables()` and thanks for highlighting this function to me - I didn't know it before. I went through the function description, it appears to report the final memory used by DT, not the maximum memory used during processing (i.e. including working memory). Not sure how these figures relate to those reported by Task Manager. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Fyi, `?tables` takes you to the help page, so that was deliberate. Similarly, you can type `?truelength` for information on how data.tables handle memory.

Comment: This is most likely due to [this bug, #921](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/921), which is already fixed in `1.9.5`. There were some unnecessary copies (regression from `1.9.0`, I think) that were happening. I'd recommend trying again on `1.9.5`.

Comment: @Arun, I installed DT 1.9.5 and re-ran the test with 200K x 2.5K DT, unfortunately, the issue persisted. I have edited my post with the new printscreen showing memory of 6.8GB after adding the single NA column.

Comment: Hm, seems like some copy is happening while simply returning a value from an internal function.. Will  try to find a more straightforward example to reproduce, and see if it's fixable. Thanks.

Comment: @Arun, glad to be of help! Kindly update us when the issue is resolved. Of course, do let me know how else I can help.

Comment: @Arun, to update you: I just tried if this 'peak memory doubling' issue has been resolved in the latest 1.9.5 - I'm afraid it's still there. I looked through Github, and there's no such issue filed yet. Shall I file one?

Comment: @NoviceProg, yes please!

Comment: Hi @Arun, FYI, I have filed an issue at Github. Hope the fix is an easy one...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(I can take no credit as the great DT minds (Arun) have been working on this and found it was related to print.data.table. Just closing the loop here for other SO users.)*

It seems this `data.table` memory issue with `:=` has been solved on R version 3.2 as noted by:
https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1062

[Quoting @Arun from Github issue 1062...]

> fixed in R v3.2, IIUC, with this item from NEWS:
>
> > Auto-printing no longer duplicates objects when printing is dispatched to a method.

So others with this problem should look to upgrading to R 3.2.

Comment: Thanks @micstr, I clean forgot I post this issue on SO. I tested it over the weekend and confirm the issue has been resolved in R3.2 for Linux. *Disclaimer: I have switched to using R in Linux so didn't test the issue in Windows.